# Assembly code outputs a ton of 'U's on virtualbox

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, bootloader

I am kind of a newbie in assembly so it can be my mistake but as far as i have researched, this program:

```
[BITS 16]    
[ORG 0x7C00]     
;============> START <=============================
Key:
mov ah,1
int 16h
mov ah,0Ah
int 10h
call Key
;============> END <===============================
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

should wait for an keyboard input and then write the ASCII character that was typed. When i run it(after i build it with NASM) it only outputs a ton of 'U' characters until it gets out of video memory(i think) after 3-4 seconds.

If it matters i use ubuntu 14.04, sublime text for the editing and a c program that first compiles the code to a .bin and then cat's the .bin to a .img that i use in virtualbox.

Comment: You want `mov ah,0`, not `mov ah,1`.

Comment: @PaulR Now it doesn't output anything.

Comment: It won't output anything until you hit a key.

Comment: I know, just added a mov bl,07 and now it works. It was outputting when i pressed the key but it was outputting a black character

Comment: You should probably use `jmp Key`, not `call Key`. Otherwise, you'll eventually overflow your stack and crash.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen ok, fixing that. Didn't know it'd cause an stack overflow. I think that is why the printing of 'U' stopped after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interrupt you're using Int 16h, AH=01h returns immediately and clears the Z flag if a keystroke is available and sets it otherwise, so your program will not wait for a keystroke.

You could wait for a keystroke either by using Int 16h, AH=00h which actually waits for a keystroke, or modify your code to make a jump until there's a keystroke, like this:

```
Key:
  mov ah,1       ;
  int 16h        ; check for keystroke - clear Z flag if keystroke, AL = char
  jz Key         ; keep looping until there is a key pressed
  xor bx,bx      ; clear BX (page = 0)
  mov cx,1       ; and rep count (1)
  mov ah,0Ah     ; write char at cursor position
  int 10h        ;
  jmp Key        ; this should be a jmp rather than a call
```